# Checking input for an int and if it's char ask for input again (Turbo C++)

Tags: c++

```
void getit()
{
     int n, x;
     cout << "Enter the number:";
     while(!(cin >> n >> x)) 
     {
         cout << "Incorrect input. Please try again.\n";
         cin.clear();
         cin.ignore();
     }
}
```

This function checks the inputted data type. If it's character, an error is shown and if an int, the function works normally. Is there any way to do this for two values at once? (TURBO C++)
I need to input coordinates of a grid and want to use the getit function only once instead of twice 
//Edit:  Needed to input coordinates of a point and check if by mistake user inputted a character. Wanted to do it at the same time for both coordinates

Comment: Please try to explain more clearly what you are asking. It would help to provide some sample input and output and explain how the output differs from what you expected.

Comment: `cin.ignore()` means to ignore 1 character . You might get better results by ignoring the remainder of the input line

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check for the ascii value.

try something like

```
void getit()
{
     bool success;
     char cn, cx;
     int n, x;

     success = false;

     cout << "Enter the number:";
     do
     {
        cin >> cn >> cx
        if(cn < '0' || cn > '9' || cx < '0' || cx > '9')
        {
            cout << "Incorrect input. Please try again.\n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore();

        }
        else
        {
            success = true;
        }

     } while(success == false);

     n = cn-30;
     x = cx-30;

     //Your Calculations Here!!!

}
```

Comment: We completely switched the code and don't need this function anymore but thanks for the solution; it's a smart one !!

Comment: Using magic numbers, downvoted. If you want to use `'0'`, write `'0'`.

Comment: @n.m. Happy now?

Comment: Not really. `cn` and `cx` are used but never assigned. A modern compiler would warn you about it.

Comment: And here i could swear i changed that line earlier. However, changed it now. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score -1):

The thing you need to check is

```
void getit()
{
        int n, x;
        while (1) 
        {   
                cout << "Enter two numbers:";
                cin >> n >> x;
                if (cin.fail())
                {   
                        cin.clear();
                        cin.ignore(50, '\n');
                        cout << "Incorrect input. Please try again.\n";
                        continue;
                }   
                else 
                {   
                        cout << "You entered " << n << " and " << x << endl;
                        break;
                }   
        }   
}
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/

Comment: I updated my code sample to be more complete. I think it is the most correct answer. It expects the cin command to correctly format integers, and fails otherwise.

Comment: Still can't figure out why my answer was downvoted. Responding to a low rated question?